# Gosth notifications in Odoo 13 EE

Tags: python, linux, odoo, odoo-13, odoo-enterprise

I have 2 instances of Odoo 13 Enterprise in the same server under linux. The first instance is production instance. The customers can connect with it with his mobiles with Odoo app. This instance works fine. The second instance is used to try new modules before put it in production instance. The problem is when I send notifications on development instance the customer get this notifications on his mobiles, and this notifications seems like production instance notification.

Important notes: Production instance is under Nginx proxy and have domain, but development instance haven't.

I'm looking for some forgoten setting, but I didn't see any mistake.

Comment: Are those Odoos using separate databases? Have you deactivated or deleted the email settings (fetchmail and outgoing mail servers)?

Comment: Yes. I use separate databases and I delete email settings (both). I only leave users because it necesary to check new code.

Comment: Then both my possibilties are gone. Deleting the email settings should be more than enough. Are you sure the second instance is using another db?

Comment: I'm completely sure. This post is because I try all thing that I know. It's an UFO.

Comment: Yes very weird indeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue uninstalling module ocn_client. This module cache some dependencies and send gosth notifications.